# Java : Writing an object to a file avoiding java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, serialization, object, stack-overflow, buffering

I want to write some large amount of data to a file. the data is contained in an object. object is implemented as serializable.
The thing is when I try to write it to a file using ObjectOutputStream's writeObject, it gives the StackOverflowError because the size of the object is large.

I only need to save the object so that i can open and use it again, change some values, and save to disk again.

The object file is a NeuralNetwork created with Neuroph framework, so i dont like to look into its big code and pick data one by one and serialize the stuff.

Please can someone suggest a way to slice the object ( or some buffering effect ) and save at least. i think that kind of thing would do the trick.

Thank you. :)

Comment: Try the `-Xss` option of the JVM.

Comment: i thank all you for the replys, i increased stack size and it helped a little. but it still fails sometimes. i found that the file size increases largely when i increase the number of nodes In A Level, Not when I Add New Levels. might be some problem with neuroph. anyway i am about to start this with Matlab. Thank You all.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you consider increasing the stack size (`-Xss2m` or so) as maybe just having more on the stack will allow you to get it done?

Beyond that there is not really a way to cut up an object graph for serialization (without understanding the objects).

Comment: +1: Other than changing the way the object is structured, this is the best option.

Comment: It can be a bit disturbing to think that you can exceed a 1Mb stack size (default on my system) with serialization ... but I exeeded this limit serializing a "rather" small tree structure with about 160,000 nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an error in Neuroph, because graphs may have cyclic paths, leading to infinite recursion.

In that case you need to do the (de-)serialization yourself. At least you will learn some. With reflection that is relatively easy, as the Neuroph framework is lean.

Do they have a decent developer forum?

Comment: Any object serialization/deserialization mechanism will be able to handle a loop in the object graph, so I doubt that's the problem here. And I certainly don't recommend doing the serialization/deserialaztion yourself, it's a lot of work to get that right.